# Accessing Filter in a Two-Level Grouping in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have a list that has a two-level grouping. How can I access the second level filter from the first ?

```
<div ng-repeat="(key1, value1) in list| groupBy: 'group1'">
  <!--i want to access 'filtered' here-->
  {{ key1 }}
  <div ng-repeat="(key2, value2) in value1 | groupBy : 'group2'" ng-show="filtered.length > 0">
    {{ key2 }}
    <div ng-repeat="item in value2 | filter : ...some filters } as filtered">
      <div class="collapse-detail-detail">
        {{ item.Name }}
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to access 'filtered' in the first level because i want to hide the whole group when there are no items under it after filter.

For example I have this list:

```
[
{name:"Kevin Durant", team: 1, : homeTown: 1}, 
{name:"Dwayne Wade", team: 2, homeTown: 1}, 
{name:"Lebron James", team: 2, homeTown: 2}, 
{name:"Kyrie Irving", team: 2, homeTown: 2},
{name:"Damian Lillard", team: 1, homeTown: 3}
]
```

grouping by team and hometown will result in

```
team 1
  homeTown 1
    Kevin Durant
  homeTown 3
    Damian Lillard
team 2
  homeTown 1
    Dwayne Wade
  homeTown 2
    Lebron James
    Kyrie Irving
```

if you will filter all who belongs in team 1 you will get:

```
team 1
  homeTown 1
    Kevin Durant
  homeTown 3
    Damian Lillard
team 2
  homeTown 1
  homeTown 2
```

but the result I want is

```
team 1
  homeTown 1
    Kevin Durant
  homeTown 3
    Damian Lillard
```

Comment: Add your Datastructure for `list`, that can help understand the problem well.

Comment: @rajeemcariazo , See the answer , its working

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Its working , You can use `angular.filter` module for grouping arrays.  [**angular.filter**](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter)

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['angular.filter']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.list = [
{name:"Kevin Durant", team: 1,  homeTown: 1}, 
{name:"Dwayne Wade", team: 1, homeTown: 1}, 
{name:"Lebron James", team: 1, homeTown: 2}, 
{name:"Kyrie Irving", team: 1, homeTown: 2},
{name:"Damian Lillard", team: 1, homeTown: 3}
] 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.4.x"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.1/angular-filter.js"></script>
   
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in list | groupBy: 'team'">
        Team: {{ key }}
         
       <ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in value | groupBy: 'homeTown'">
         <span>HomeTown: {{ key }}<span>
         <div style="margin-left:10px;"> <span ng-repeat="subValue in value">{{subValue.name}}{{($index < value.length - 1 ? ", " : "")}}</span></div>
    
       </ul> 
      </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: this doesn't answer my question, my question is how I can remove groups that do not have items after filter

Comment: @rajeemcariazo I updated json with all belongs to team1 , its working. You are looking for any other solution?